# Access ELB from inside the VPC using domain name and subdomain without going to outside internet

Tags: aws-elb

How can I access a subdomain from inside VPC going thru the ELB.
Let's say have 3 EC2 instances, two of them are running an endpoint API that go thru the Load Balance, and the third one is accessing their API.
I have a domain added to Route 53 that has a subdomain for the API endpoint which I am trying to access from within the VPC, is this possible?
What I am trying to do: EC2-3 -> api.mysite.com (stay inside VPC) -> LoadBalancer -> Target group -> either instance 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

create a private zone , associate it with the vpc that the resources are deployed in and then create an alias record that points to elb .

That pvt zone will be resolvable without leaving the network , just ensure that your elb is an internal loadbalancer